# int cannot be converted to int[][] while invoking the function

Tags: java, arrays

i tried to code a divide and conquer algorithm that finds an element in 2d array.

Function prototype:

```
public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target)
```

Invoking:

```
 x=searchMatrix(matrix[(rows-1)/2][columns],target);
```

Error is while invoking this int cannot be converted into int[][]

rows is calculated in the beginning as matrix.length and columns as matrix[0].length

Comment: You're looking up an int in the array `matrix` and then calling the method with it. The method expects a reference to the array, not an int. Hence compiler complaining.

Comment: `matrix[(rows-1)/2][columns]` is the integer stored at that specific location, not the array. What do you want to achieve with that statement? Pass the array starting at an offset?

Comment: got it thank you very much. How can i pass a certain portion of matrix?

Comment: I want to pass half of the array

Comment: @VarunChopra You should create another matrix (another variable of the same type -> int[][]) and set the values in the positions you need

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass half of the array

You can create a separate half array from the original `matrix` array and pass it to your `searchMatrix` method.

```
int[][] halfMatrix = new int[(rows-1)/2][columns];
for(int i=0;i<(rows-1)/2; i++) {
  for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
    halfMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
  }
}

 x=searchMatrix(halfMatrix,target);
```

If you are trying to employ `divide and conquer` tactic, which might not be really fruitful from performance point of view, you can do it the following way:

```
int[][] halfMatrix = new int[(rows-1)/2][columns];
int[][] secondHalfMatrix = new int[(rows+1)/2][columns];
for(int i=0;i<(rows-1)/2; i++) {
  for(int j=0;j<columns;j++) {
    if(i<(rows-1)/2)
      halfMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    else
      secondHalfMatrix[i-(rows-1)/2][j] = matrix[i][j];
  }
}

 x=searchMatrix(halfMatrix,target) || searchMatrix(secondHalfMatrix,target);
```

Comment: If i am trying to use divide and conquer i have to do this every time?

Comment: See my edits that address the `divide and conquer` requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep sending in the same array, you could add two parameters to show the length and height:

```
public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int rows, int cols, int target)
```

and later call it as:

```
x=searchMatrix(matrix,(rows-1)/2,columns,target);
```

And the initial call would have the original number of rows and columns.

**Edit**

If you want to pass different parts of the array, you could have an extra parameter telling the number of rows and columns. Generically, this could be something of use.

```
x=searchMatrix(matrix, rowStartIndex, noOfRows, columnStartIndex, noOfColumns, target);
```

Comment: He wants a divide an conquer... Maybe he should pass the starting column and row as well.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi, yeah, that's a better idea. The OP seemed to ask he only sends the first half of rows with the columns unchanged, but I guess a generic answer is always more useful.